# laravel create trigger with migration throws error or access violation

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, laravel-5.4, laravel-migrations

I created a trigger to check if the value is between a specified range. Now i wanted to make a migration for it but i receive the following error:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>      corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter |
>                 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS header_range_limit |
>                 ' at line 1

my migration looks like

```
class HeaderRangeTrigger extends Migration
{
/**
 * Create trigger. Checks if a value is > 100 or < 0, sets to 50 is so
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    DB::unprepared('
    delimiter |
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS header_range_limit |
        CREATE TRIGGER header_range_limit BEFORE
        UPDATE
        ON
          user_settings FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.header_position < 0 OR NEW.header_position > 100 THEN
        SET NEW.header_position = 50; 
          END IF; 
        END |
        delimiter ;
    ');
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS header_range_limit');
}
```

}

I also tried different delimiter but with the same result.

If I copy & paste the code in phpmyadmin SQL Editor, it works without any problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function up()
{

    $procedure ="DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetInstagramPerContest;

       CREATE PROCEDURE GetInstagramPerContest(IN  p_contest_id INT(11))
       BEGIN
                select sum(tt.instatagspercontest) from (
                select latest_tags_count as instatagspercontest from ENInstagramTagsCount where contest_id= p_contest_id
                 UNION
                select latest_tags_count as tweetspercontest from CHZHInstagramTagsCount where contest_id= p_contest_id
                 UNION
                select latest_tags_count as tweetspercontest from JPInstagramTagsCount where contest_id= p_contest_id
                 UNION
                select latest_tags_count as tweetspercontest from KRInstagramTagsCount where contest_id= p_contest_id ) as tt;
        END
        ";



    DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($procedure);

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::unprepared("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetInstagramPerContest");

}
```